# Share RAID between Linux and Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, raid, software-raid

I have a PC with two SSD, one for Windows 10 and one for Linux.
I also have two more 1TB disks that I want to use as a software RAID 1 volume shared between Windows and Linux OS.
Which way could be preferred to implement this?
Also which file system could be used on this volume?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment much on the RAID side of things.  Your best bet there is probably to either get a hardware RAID card, or use some firmware provided implementation (Intel's firmware 'RAID' is pretty well supported by Linux, but I've not used it myself so I really can't say if it will work for you or not).

For the filesystem though, use NTFS.  Windows supports it natively, and NTFS-3G on Linux covers almost everything you're likely to actually need, including transparent compression, symbolic links, hard links, and mapping file ownership (though that requires some manual setup).  It also doesn't suffer from the file size or performance limitations that FAT32 does, or the usability problems that exFAT and UDF have on Linux.